# How to write mysql regular expression in where clause?

Tags: mysql, regex

How do I write a regular expression in where clause to match the following patterns

Pattern 1

```
~
~ ~
~ ~ ~
```

Pattern 2

```
~ ~ |A~b
~ ~ ~|A~b~c
~ ~ ~|this can be anything
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~|this can be anything
```

For pattern 2 just need to match the part before |.

Comment: Something like `REGEXP '^[~ ]{2,6}|.*';`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^~([ ]+~)*[ ]*(\\|.*|$)
```

Try this.If you have space before first `~` use

```
^[ ]*~([ ]+~)*[ ]*(\\|.*|$)
```

See demo.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b67085/3/0

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this is also brining ~B~ ~ ~|3~1~2~0~ in the result. There should not be anything between ~'s

Comment: Hi, Sometimes I am getting this error when  I execute the query. Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp. Any ideas?

Comment: @anything https://www.dionach.com/blog/mysql-regex-conditional-errors-and-sql-injection